# Zend Framework deployment to a subdomain

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to develop some application. I develop on my localhost and then I upload it to some subdomain like abc.mydomain.com. When I upload my layout index.phtml, I get the following for all URLs:

```
abc.mydomain.com/css/base.css 404 (Not Found)
```

on the web browser console but my CSS is in the public folder.

my code to link this css is :

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/base.css') ?>
```

What should i do to make these addresses work ?

To complete my question : How does the framework distinguish between a folder and a controller or How could i tell the framework to don't act on these URL ass action , they are folders ?

Comment: did your configure your virtual host for `abc.mydomain.com`?

Comment: i do in my local Apache but i don't have access to server Virtual host and i could just create sub domain witch directed to folder .

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` in place?

Comment: Try to use Google Translate and similar tools to correct your language, before you post questions, please! It's quite a pain to correct such posts.

Comment: .htaccess is in place . I now use full address but it is not good solution .

Comment: I was thinking all traffic goes to public folder and then all request in public folder goes to index.php and i should do something in index.php .

Comment: Usually all these type of issues are related to configs (virthost or symbolic links)... Did you create all the necessary symbolic links for static content directories?

Comment: Yes i think because it works on main domain and as all addresses are partial they don't need to be change and all part works good except this CSS addressing .

Comment: Let's chat in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21501/zend-framework-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a mapping issue associated to the hosting the subdomain. Often on shared hosting you cannot map the project's `public` folder to the subdomain. So a variety of rewrite tricks are required to map requests for pages and assets into the right directories without confusing ZF about the requested URL.

Check out:

http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/

for a description of the problem and various approaches to solving it.

Comment: Excuse me but i got same error on non share domain with same files and same confines.

Comment: It's not the sharing per se, but the mapping. If you can't map to `public` to the root of your subdomain, then you have to take special steps. Any of those steps outlined in the blog post - my method of pushing the entire application into a protected directory of the special `.htacess` rules identified in the links or in the comments - should do the job.

Comment: My problem on the non shared server solved by changing Virtual directory on Apache2 sites-available and point to public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `baseUrl()` view-helper detects (internally, using the `Zend_Controller_Front::getBaseUrl()` method) what your app's base-url is.

But sometimes, depending upon your vhost setup and the location of your public folder within the doc root - you need to tell the app explicitly what your base-url is.

In `application/configs/applicatiom.ini`, you can set:

`resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://abc.mydomain.com"`

Then in a view-script, you can access public assets using the `baseUrl()` view-helper and a *relative* url (relative to the base you set), as follows:

`<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/base.css')) ?>`

though I see many people use it as a prefix-only:

`<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl() . '/css/base.css') ?>`

Comment: Thank's for your answer but when i define baseUrl in application.ini i get same error (Not found) , framework don't recognize the diffrence between Folder's and Controller's in subdomian but it works fine in main domain and  i don't know why .

Comment: Are you using the `baseUrl()` view-helper?

Comment: Yes i did exactly as you say and then I've tried all possible way on you'r solution .

Comment: Yeah, from the question-level comments, it appears that the issue is not incorrect use of `baseUrl()` but rather a vhost/subdomain/hosting issue.

Comment: I don't think so , because all functionality works fine except this CSS addressing, vhost is out of my hand in the server and subdomain is  set just fine . Don't you think i should do some thing in the main index.php to tell the framework this is not a controller, it is a folder , if it is possible ?